# Delete from table is very slow in oracle standard edition

Tags: oracle, performance, sql-delete

Delete on table in oracle standard edition(no partition) gets slow with time.

Important Info: I am working on oracle standard edition so partitioning option available.

Detail:
I have one table with no constraint on it (no PK or anyother key or trigger or index or anything).

More than a million record gets inserted in this table in every 15 min using sql loader.

we need to process this 15 min record in every 15 min and at end of process delete any record older than 30 minute so that at any point of time there is more than  30-40 minute of data in the table.

Problem:

As time passes due to so frequent insertion and deletion response from the table gets slow. 
Data extraction and delete from table takes more time with every passing run.

After a while even a simple select query takes too long.

We cant truncate table as data loader runs continously and we may loose data if truncate and we dont have create table access to drop and create table.

we have to process data in every 15 minute and made it available to downstream for further processing. it just keep getting slow.

Kindly help me with the aforementioned situation.

Comment: Are you doing a direct-path load?  In which case, new data always goes above the high water mark, space is never reused when data is deleted, and the cost of a table scan will constantly increase?  If you are deleting based on a timestamp, why is that timestamp not indexed?

Comment: Hi @JustinCave : thanks for the reply, we are trying option of indexing timestamp, however could please provide more info about the recommended way of loading data.